# What is Java equivalent of this Perl http POST

Tags: java, perl, http, post

(First Stack Overlflow question!)
I'm having a hard time coding the equivalent form-data http POST in Java based on the Perl example below.  I've even used WireShark to try to capture this working example so I can study the XML data being posted so I can code that in Java, but no dice.  Does anyone know what this XML from the code below would look like?  I can authenticate fine, but the form data keeps being rejected in my Java code.

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->timeout($MYTIMEOUT);
$ua->credentials("myweb03:80","mydomain.com",$user, $password);

my $response = $ua->post($PEPSURL, 'content-type' => 'form-data',
                                 Content => {
                                 username => $user,
                                 prep_id => $prep_id,
                                 project => $project,
                                 upfile  => [ $uploadfile ],
                                 discussion => $discussion,
                                 silentsave => int($silentFlag)

             });
```

Comment: There is no XML at all. At least as Java developer I can't see it.

Comment: What XML? This submits a `POST` request with a message body containing data encoded as `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working thanks to those answering this question as well as a key code example from http://indiwiz.com/2009/02/11/multi-part-content-upload-in-apache-http-components-http-client/.
This is an example of how to do a multipart/form-data post, uploading a text file in the process:

```
package upfile;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class Upfile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("<host>", 80, "<realm>", "basic"),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("<username>", "<password>"));
            HttpPost httpPost = new    HttpPost("<url>");
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
            entity.addPart("username", new StringBody("<username>", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            entity.addParPart("id", new StringBody("86815", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            entity.addPart("project", new StringBody("GIZMO", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            entity.addPart("discussion", new StringBody("Discussion text; uploaded via Java!", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            File f = new File("/Users/sjd/myFile.txt");
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(f, "text/plain");
            entity.addPart("upfile", fileBody);
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println("Response content length: " + 
                     entity.getContentLength());
                ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(outstream);
                byte[] responseBody = outstream.toByteArray();
                System.out.println(responseBody.toString());
            }
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } finally {        
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "built" in post method in Java.  You could build one, or you could try [Apache's HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) API, in particular, the `HttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

derosast:

You are using this form of LWP::UserAgent->post:

```
$ua->post( $url, $field_name => $value,... Content => \%form )
```

According to the documentation for [LWP::UserAgent](http://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent):

> This method will dispatch a POST request on the given $url, with %form
>   or @form providing the key/value pairs for the fill-in form content.
>   Additional headers and content options are the same as for the get()
>   method.
>
> This method will use the POST() function from HTTP::Request::Common to
>   build the request. See HTTP::Request::Common for a details on how to
>   pass form content and other advanced features.

From [HTTP::Request::Common](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP%3a%3aRequest%3a%3aCommon):

```
POST 'http://www.perl.org/survey.cgi',
       Content_Type => 'form-data',
       Content      => [ name  => 'Gisle Aas',
                         email => 'gisle@aas.no',
                         gender => 'M',
                         born   => '1964',
                         init   => ["$ENV{HOME}/.profile"],
                       ]
```

CREATES:

```
  POST http://www.perl.org/survey.cgi
  Content-Length: 388
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="6G+f"

  --6G+f
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

  Gisle Aas
  --6G+f
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

  gisle@aas.no
  --6G+f
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gender"

  M
  --6G+f
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="born"

  1964
  --6G+f
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="init"; filename=".profile"
  Content-Type: text/plain

  PATH=/local/perl/bin:$PATH
  export PATH

  --6G+f--
```

So the other posters are correct.  The format is not XML.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Extremely helpful and very kind to take the time to help.  I have new hope.  If I get this working, I will save my co-workers hours every week by automating our bug submission system.  Thanks very much!